# Is it possible to change target device for entire solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, emulation

I've got a visual studio solution with 40 windows mobile projects in it.  Because the application uses a form of IoC/DI, almost all of the projects need to be deployed by visual studio.  (Yes, it's a lot.  If I could start over again, I would make an effort to keep the number of projects to a minimum.)

I debug the application using a number of different emulators.  Whenever I want to debug the application on a different emulator, I have to go through each of the projects and change its 'Target Device' property to the appropriate emulator.

Is there an easy way to do this for the entire solution?  Thanks.

Comment: use something such as powershell to directly update the .proj files....

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I considered something like that, but wouldn't that mean closing/re-opening the solution?  That's kinda messy, but might still be better than what I'm currently doing.

Comment: You can (and should) perform this without the solution open, then re-open once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your target for each to Windows CE, which will allow you to target any device.  Once you've done that, simply expand the solution node so you can see all projects then hold down shift and/or alt and multi select all of the projects (I usually just select the first, hold shift and select the last) and then set the target device.

Comment: Thank you.  This is what I was hoping for.  I didn't realize that selecting WinCe would let you choose any of your available emulators.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. You rock!